# How this gsub() works?

Tags: r, gsub

So, it's the code and I don't understand the output.

Original theStr:"C:\\Users\\codep\\Desktop\\DM_HW2\\2017-07-9.csv"

```
gsub("^(.*)\\\\.*$",'\\1',theStr)
```

it become:"C:\\Users\\codep\\Desktop\\DM_HW2"

what is the "\\\\." in the pattern and the '\\1' in the replacement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: You can use a mere `sub` here, you only perform a single replace operation. `^(.*)\\.*$` can be well-explained [at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wHHOTn/1).

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern may be explained as follows:

```
^(.*)\\\\   - match and capture everything up but excluding the LAST path separator
.*$         - then match/consume the remainder of the file path
```

Then, you replace the original input with the captured quantity, which is `\\1`, the second parameter passed to `gsub`.  This effectively removes everything from the final path separator to the end of the file path.

Here is a regex demo which you can use to see for yourself how the pattern is matching, and what the capture group is:

### Demo